# Anonymous callback functions in Python 2.7.5?

Tags: python, events, callback, wxpython, anonymous-function

I'm trying to decouple GUI and Logic in a wxPython application using python 2.7.5. Since wxPython uses event binding I thought I'd extend this approach. Summarizing my code:

GUI.py

```
class MainInterface():
    def __SetupControlPanel(self, controlPanel):
        self.DoSomethingButton = wx.Button(controlPanel, wx.ID_ANY, "Do something")

    def BindCallback_DoSomething(self, callback):
        self.frame.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, callback, self.DoSomethingButton)
```

main.py

```
def DoSomething(event):
    someLogicClass.DoSomething()

interface.BindEvent_DoSomething(DoSomething)
```

This decouples the two parts of the application nicely, but I don't like the way I have to define a separate function in main.py for every callback, as it usually just calls a single logic function. From a JS background, I'm used to being able to use an anonymous function. I'd imagine something like this would make my code somewhat more compact:

```
interface.BindEvent_DoSomething(def (event):
    someLogicClass.DoSomething()
)
```

Is there any way to achieve such syntax in Python?

Comment: Have you searched for "python anonymous functions"?

Comment: I have, but none the lambda function examples I found showed that it was possible to simply call a method... guess I missed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can try with a lambda function:

```
interface.BindEvent_DoSomething(lambda event: someLogicClass.DoSomething())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use lambda function

```
interface.BindEvent_DoSomething(lambda e: doSomething())
```